# Efficient solution of huge sparse linear system

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

I'm trying to improve efficiency of my code in which main task is a solution to huge (~$10^4\times 10^4$) but sparse linear system
$$Ax=b$$
(In fact my aim is to solve nonlinear equations $F(x)=0$, but the problem can be reduced with Newton's method to iterative procedure, with $A=J=F'(x)$ as Jacobian matrix of a system, for which I have an explicit form. Since I have good guess for a starting point it takes only 1-2 steps for `FindRoot` to converge, but it consumes great ammount of RAM ~9GB, which increases with number of steps taken). The problem is both the time it takes for *Mathematica* to get the solution and the ammount of memory it uses e.g.

```
LinearSolve[A, b, Method-> "Multifrontal"]
```

takes around 140s (from the beginning it works on two cores) while the memory consumption is enormous, with a peak of 6GB (where it comes from?). Thanks to the question [(82645)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82645/linearsolve-and-krylov-method-options) I've found the `"Pardiso"` method which is better in terms of memory (at the beginning it consumes only 1GB, at the end ~3.1GB) but is much slower 415s. Interesting thing about `"Pardiso"` is that for most of the time (6*60s) it uses only one core, then for the next 60s it uses two (see CPU load graph below; 2 physical cores with HT) and consumes additional 2.1GB of RAM. What it does at these phases (unpacking sparse array, data transfer to MKLs Pardiso solver)?

[image]

Is there any chance to improve efficiency for this problem? Both in terms of execution time and memory consumption? Matrix $A$ is quite sparse (density $\leq 1\%$), at the end of the day I would like to increase size of the the problem (dimension of $A$) wich with current timings will make it impossible.

I think that this is independent problem of any details of the system (its sparsity pattern). Below I've uploaded files with compressed (use `Uncompress[]`) [$A$ matrix](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0cpisroKNyAMXNON2FuSG95QlE/view?usp=sharing) (large file 80MB) and [$b$ vector](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0cpisroKNyAZFhMVEZnMDl6dzg/view?usp=sharing) (the $32769\times 32769$ test case).

I'm suspecting that `FindRoot` uses `"Multifrontal"` method internally in this case (consistent timings, but for 2 intermediate steps I see that it consumes ~1.5 times memory as `LinearSolve`). Iterative methods are not an option here (as far as I know) since these take forever (both for `` SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve[] `` and `LinearSolve[..., Method -> "Krylov"]` as these seem to be equivalent).

Comment: Is `A` constructed as an explicit `SparseArray`? If not, try making it one to see if that improves on memory use and/or `LinearSolve` speed.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationSpecifyingDerivatives.html)?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, $A$ is constructed as `SparseArray` object. @J.M. Yes I've seen that, I'm calling `FindRoot` with specified Jacobian function `FindRoot[F[X], {X, X0}, 
 Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch", 
   "UpdateJacobian" -> 1}, Jacobian :> J[X], AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 10]` with `F` and `J` a 'black box' functions.

Comment: I suppose that one solution would be to explicitly call Pardiso solver from Fortran and use `LibraryLink`. I'll try to experiment with that later today.

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while since this question was asked but perhaps a sketch of an answer is useful for future reference. In version 12.0 `FindRoot` got a new method option for an *Affine Corvariant Newton* solver that is fairly efficient for large scale sets of equations. It achieves this performance by making use of a few tricks.

1. It's optimized to use minimal Jacobian evaluations.
2. It makes use of Broyden updates.
3. It stores the Jacobian decomposition that is computed with `LinearSolve` with the method "Pardiso".

Since your post concentrated more on the `LinearSolve` aspect I can not test `FindRoot` with your application. For `LinearSolve` you should make use the Method option "Pardiso" as that is quite efficient.

You can also use Iterative solves - which may or may not be efficient in your case. Since you have a good starting value, this might pan out. If you feel like it you could replace the entire 'LinearSolve` command with something geared towards your specific problem.

For more information of the use of the [Affine Covariant Newton solver](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationAffineCovariantNewton.html) I'd like to refer you to the documentation